# How to align text in flutter with respect to a separator in middle?

Tags: flutter

How can I align text to the center with a separator as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: Please add code, in which you tried to create this

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved using combination of Expanded and Align. Below one is the code which you can use to accomplish the same behavior.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                      child: Text("Test"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(" : "),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                      child: new Text("123"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                      child: Text("Test 123"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(" : "),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                      child: new Text("9337822"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                      child: Text("Test 123 123"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(" : "),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                      child: new Text("111888999999"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give you logic because you didn't provide the relevant code and also you are new here.

Take `Row` Widget with three `Text` widgets as children as you can show in your image. Wrap 1st and 3rd `Text` with `Expanded` widget and set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` of `Row` Widget. And also you have to set alignment of all `Text` widgets like 1st has right, 2nd has center and 3rd has left alignment.

Thats it :)

> ~PS : You have to repeat for each row *(Based on your image look)*, may be easy with `List` widget or etc.